# r If I have two seperate groups that have the same contents, how can I delete one of them?

Tags: r, dataframe

The actual dataframes that my code is dealing with are much larger than this one and it needs to be able to deal with different dataframes.  The example below is to illustrate the problem of having groups with the same contents, and how to only keep one of them.

Consider the case where I have groups with different contents.

```
Group   Contents
GroupA  Marble
GroupB  Marble
GroupB  Granite
GroupC  Marble
GroupD  Granite
GroupD  Glass
GroupD  Marble
```

In the example above, GroupA and GroupC both only contain marble, so I would like to delete one of these groups.  My desired output:

```
Group   Contents
GroupA  Marble
GroupB  Marble
GroupB  Granite
GroupD  Granite
GroupD  Glass
GroupD  Marble
```

Reproducible data:

```
structure(list(Group = c("GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupC", 
"GroupD", "GroupD", "GroupD"), Contents = c("Marble", "Marble", 
"Granite", "Marble", "Granite", "Glass", "Marble")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Contents = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: So if a group has two same `Contents` you would delete that as well? Meaning if groupA has Marble, Granite and Group C also has Marble, Granite then you would delete both of those group?

Comment: If group A contained Marble and Granite and group C contained Marble and Granite then I would want to delete one of these groups.

Comment: I do not want two groups in my dataframe that have exactly the same contents

Comment: Which one are you going to give priority if the scenario you mentioned occurs? And on what basis? Of the two any one can be deleted.

Comment: I do not care which one of the groups is deleted.

Comment: How big is your data? How many rows and columns?

Comment: My data is 2 columns and 500 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
idx <- !duplicated(with(df, cbind(Contents, ave(Contents, Group, FUN = function(x) toString(sort(x))))))
          
df[idx, ]

   Group Contents
1 GroupA   Marble
2 GroupB   Marble
3 GroupB  Granite
5 GroupD  Granite
6 GroupD    Glass
7 GroupD   Marble
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `dplyr` filter function:-

```
df<-structure(list(Group = c("GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupC", 
                         "GroupD", "GroupD", "GroupD"), Contents = c("Marble", "Marble", 
                                                                     "Granite", "Marble", "Granite", "Glass", "Marble")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                              -7L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Group = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), Contents = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec")) 
df
df%>%
  filter(Group!="GroupC")


 Group Contents
1 GroupA   Marble
2 GroupB   Marble
3 GroupB  Granite
4 GroupD  Granite
5 GroupD    Glass
6 GroupD   Marble
```

Comment: My actual dataset is much larger. This was an example to illustrate my problem.  This will not work in practice

Comment: How do you mean, that it wont work in practice? The solution I provided replicated your desired output.

Comment: The actual dataframes that my code is dealing with are much larger than this one and it needs to be able to deal with different dataframes.

Comment: @RobinTurkington Your answer assumes that you already know which group to remove (`GroupC`) but in reality that is not the case. You need to programatically find out the group to remove based on the `Contents` column.

Comment: My apologies, thank you for clearing that up @Ronak. I think you have your solution below, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option via nested `aggregate`

```
df[df$Group %in% aggregate(Group~.,aggregate(.~Group,df,toString),head,1)$Group,]
```

- Output

```
   Group Contents
1 GroupA   Marble
2 GroupB   Marble
3 GroupB  Granite
5 GroupD  Granite
6 GroupD    Glass
7 GroupD   Marble
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     arrange(across(everything())) %>%
     group_by(Group) %>%
     mutate(new = toString(Contents)) %>%
     ungroup %>%
     distinct(Contents, new, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     select(-new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Group  Contents
#  <chr>  <chr>   
#1 GroupA Marble  
#2 GroupB Granite 
#3 GroupB Marble  
#4 GroupD Glass   
#5 GroupD Granite 
#6 GroupD Marble
```